# How to compare dates or filter data based on Date in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to fetch data for a particular date, datatype for this column is DateTime.
Tried below query:-

```
SELECT * from table_name where transaction_date=convert(DATETIME,'02/21/2017',101)
```

But above query is not working and returning no result, please could someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In your table do you have a valid time in the Time section? or is it 00:00:00? Converting this way out puts time as "Zero"

Comment: There is valid time.

Comment: So all your times in the table looks like this 2017-02-21 00:00:00.000?

Comment: Nopes there is valid time in DB like 2017-02-21 22:00:01.001

Comment: SELECT convert(DATETIME,'02/21/2017',101) Always return the date as 2017-02-21 00:00:00.000. 2017-02-21 00:00:00.000 != 2017-02-21 22:00:01.001

Comment: How to do it then?

Comment: You need to search for the whole day. WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN convert(DATETIME,'02/21/2017',101) AND DATEADD(S,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1,convert(DATETIME,'02/21/2017',101))) Something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need compare dates with day precision you can use datediff function as below.

```
SELECT * 
from table_name 
where datediff(dd,transaction_date,convert(DATETIME,'02/21/2017',101))=0
```

[More information about DateDiff](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X47295.htm)